# ddrescue: safe to stop while "Splitting failed blocks"?

Tags: hard-drive, data-recovery

Trying to clone a failing disk with ddrescue

> sudo ddrescue -r 3 /path/to/home /destination/ logfile

It's been running for about 10 days! Now it's *Splitting failed blocks* and hasn't read anything successfully for the past two days.

Is it safe to *Ctrl+c* ddrescue now? Will the so-far rescued image be usable if I do so?

Comment: ddrescue has already done one pass, copied most parts of the drive. Now it's trying to split and copy failed blocks. Shouldn't it be safe to stop it without corrupting anything?

Comment: So, Im concerned that, although the comments posted are useful. The actual question still remains unanswered:
That is:
Can i stop it now, and will I be able to access the rescued data if I stop it during the "Splitting Failed Blocks" phase?

Answer (score 2):

This is from [the ddrescue manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/manual/ddrescue_manual.html):

> IMPORTANT! If you interrupt the rescue and then reboot, any partially
>   copied partitions should be hidden before allowing them to be touched
>   by any operating system that tries to mount and "fix" the partitions
>   it sees.

Comment: Understandable. I'm booting from Live CD and won't mount the source partition automatically. I wouldn't want to disturb it. Rescued is the image file which won't be mounted automatically anyways. My worry is, since the ddrescue operation is incomplete, if I terminate now, will I be able to mount the rescued Image file at all? so that I could attempt extracting data from it.

Comment: A cool feature of ddrescue is that you can stop and resume its activity. It will use the log file to pick up where it stopped last. I don't think you can mount the image file.

Answer (score 0):

The command

```
fdisk -l /path/to/image
```

will show you the block-size and the start-block of the partition. You can use that to calculate the offset. Say blocksize is 512 and start block is say 128; `512*128=65536`

So `65536` is your offset you can then mount it with the command

```
mount -o loop,offset=65536 /path/to/image.img /mnt/tmp
```

or whatever mount point you want mounted.

Job done.

Answer (score 0):

According to the mail exchange there, it should be safe to stop it. Hopefully your most critical data is not in one of the failed blocks.

https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-ddrescue/2010-12/msg00012.html

> I canceled it and got most of the data I needed